# Insert new column with ascending number by column id in a R dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I'm working with R and I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(
    tree_id=c("t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2"),
    branch_id=c("b1","b1","b1","b1","b1","b1","b1","b3","b3","b1","b1","b1","b1","b2","b2","b2","b2","b2"),
    bud_id_rank=c("1","2","4","7","9","12","15","1","3","1","2","5","9","1","5","7","8","12")
    )
```

I would like to add a new column called "new_rank" which has ascending numbers from 1 based on
branch_id and tree_id. The result should be like this:

```
df<-data.frame(
    tree_id=c("t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2"),
    branch_id=c("b1","b1","b1","b1","b1","b1","b1","b3","b3","b1","b1","b1","b1","b2","b2","b2","b2","b2"),
    bud_id_rank=c("1","2","4","7","9","12","15","1","3","1","2","5","9","1","5","7","8","12"),
    new_rank=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","1","2","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","5")

    )
```

Is there any function that doest it quickly with for example the package plyr?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you now already which package to use I wonder why you are not able to figure that out yourself.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(tree_id,branch_id), transform, new_rank = seq_along(branch_id))
```

If your dataset is huge, data.table would be faster:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, new_rank:=seq_along(bud_id_rank), by=list(tree_id, branch_id)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought that plyr could do the job, but I wasn't able to find the right function.